# How do semiconductor devices break when hot?

Tags: temperature, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

When a diode gets too hot it may start to conduct in both directions,
and it may remain this way even after cooled down. What happens in this
process?

I found some answers that suggest melting. However, we can tell that
devices don't need to get that hot. We can look at some overheated LEDs,
and since the part of plastic in direct contact with the die does not
seem carbonized. Also sometimes we seem to break a diode just by heating
it with a soldering iron.

Comment: Electrical engineering problems (shortcircuits, breaks, differences in thermal expansion, etc, etc). There is a different SE for that.

Comment: Not to mention diffusion of dopants. For your LED, since the plastic is in contact with the surface it acts as a bit of a heat sink - the inside can well do bad things yet not destroy the plastic. And I certainly have shown I can explode integrated circuits just fine, so charring can well occur as well (even seen tiny little flames coming out of the crater formed in the plastic packaging that once was over the chip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semiconductor devices exhibit a resistance to the flow of electricity which *goes down* when the temperature of the device rises, because the increase in temperature increases the density of charge carriers in the semiconductor. This means that as the semiconductor heats up, the current flowing through it increases. This means more heat is dissipated in it, and its temperature rises even more.

This positive feedback loop is called *thermal runaway* which, if not checked by a current-limiting safety circuit, will cause the device to get so hot that the dopants in the silicon begin to thermally diffuse through the junction regions, destroying them and causing the device to fry and suddenly fail, going out in a puff of hot smoke.

(The general rule for semiconductors is that if they get as hot as they were during their manufacture, then the junction structures will be ruined by diffusion as described above.)

Comment: _"as hot as they were during their manufacture"_ — that's well above melting point: Czochralski process is part of the manufacture. It's not necessary to get to as high a temperature to destroy a pn junction.

Comment: by *manufacture* I mean the silicon substrate temperatures present during thin film deposition processes and diffusion processes.

Comment: Could you please recommend a book on this subject?

Comment: I cannot, but any college engineering text that deals with semiconductor processing technology will cover this in detail.